# PostgreSQL Multi Master Single Slave Replication

Tags: replication, postgresql-9.4, slony

I have multiple transaction PostgresQL 9.4 databases and a single publication read-only database. Is there any replication mechanism (asynchronous) to push every updated transaction from every database to the one publication database. Is there any work around Slony to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.